# How do I handle a bladder infection and my job?

Tags: sickness, software-development

I hope the title makes sense. I'm young and on my first job and just encountered a very uncomfortable situation I don't know how to react to.

There's more threads on how to handle illness at work but I think this is different. The very reason to consider staying at home is that going may be worse for my reputation at my job.

I didn't see my doctor yet but I'm very likely to have a bladder infection or something because I have pain and, what's worse, mild incontinence. Last friday at work I noticed a very subtle but noticeable smell of urine and thought it was some cleaning product in another room or something, turns out it was urine and it was me (without my control), and I didn't do anything about it for hours. I don't want that to happen ever again, however, it happened a couple times at home this weekend. The amount is very small, not even enough to leave a stain in my pants (or I didn't notice...), but as I said it smelled.

A friend told me this doesn't warrant a sick day because I obviously can do my job. However, I'm really scared of pissing myself. What am I supposed to do about this?

I could bring a change of underwear in a bag and if it happens change in the bathroom (and hope there's not a second time), I admittedly find that very shameful though.

I thought about talking with my manager and suggesting working from home a few days, then after that maybe come back if it doesn't happen in a while, even if the antibiotic treatment isn't over yet. My job can be done from home, as indicated in the tags it's software development.

On a side note, I also think it's in my best interest to bring this up with my manager anyway so if he noticed something last friday now he knows it's not my fault. And even if I go to work tomorrow he should know I may have to leave. I have no idea how to bring it up though.

Comment: @JimG. No. This happens without my control.

Comment: @JimG. No offense, but I don't see the parallel between someone who needs to make frequent trips to the bathroom, and someone who is soiling themselves at their desk.

Comment: I don't think this needs discussion, see your doctor.  They will advise if you are fit for work.  If you are concerned about accidents there are sanitary products available (male and female) in most supermarkets or pharmacies in most of the world. - voting to close

Comment: There are adult diapers that are practically invisible which you could try out. You can get them in healthcare shops.

Comment: Get pads.  See your doctor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Take a day off as sick and go to the doctor. Your health is more important than the job. Take it from there. Just phone into work in the morning to say that you are ill. Get a sick note if this is necessary (in the UK this is not needed unless you are ill for a week or more)
2. Do not worry about the other day. Probably nobody noticed and if they did it has been forgotten.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the quick response. My plan was to go to the doc today rather than tomorrow, it won't be mine but there's always someone just in case. Regardless, what do I do about the other days in the week? I was told this takes 8 days to treat. And that's if it is what I expect.

Comment: Please get to the Doctor - if you do not get it sorted it may get worse

Comment: I hit enter to write in the next line and it sent the comment, I'm sorry, please notice my edit.

Comment: Just take the week off sick (as you have an illness). Perhaps explain that you can do some work from home. Most (all?) people understand. Humans that work are allowed to be ill. Would they prefer you go to work and spread the infection around

Comment: I'm honestly thinking that makes more sense than my friend's advice. Thanks a lot, I didn't accept your answer yet just because I'm waiting for more input. Going to the doc now, I'll probably update you when I'm back.

Comment: Good luck - Perhaps in a few days you be as right as rain

Comment: @RisenPhoenix, go to the doctor ASAP.  Also look into getting some adult diapers.  Can usually be found in your local pharmacy near the tampons.  << That was a sentence I never thought I'd write on this site.

Comment: @EdHeal I'm back. I have no diagnosis, I was told it's no infection and it could be a prostate issue I should get looked at. After talking to a relative that had a similar experience I actually think this doc might be wrong, I'll see my usual doc in a couple days, let's see what he says. For now I have no diagnosis and no solution, just the advice of not holding it in and drinking less water at work. Well...

Comment: @djohnson10 I don't know how that looks but wouldn't it be noticeable from the shape?

Comment: @RisenPhoenix, I'm not sure.  But probably less so than the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

First go to the Dr.   If you need to go to the Dr. on a work day then tell them you need to go the Dr.  Tell them it is most likely not a medical emergency but something you need to have treated immediately.  Once you have seen the Dr then you have more information.  For example I am on antibiotics and it would be much better for me if I could work from home for the next X days. It is up to you if you want to share it is a bladder infection or not.